# Seeing which line can be debugged in firefox

Tags: javascript, debugging, firefox

I have a script with around 30 lines, and I'm trying to to debug it in firefox, but when I get the error it doesn't tell me what line is getting the error? It says 4:370, does it mean at line 370, but I only have 30 lines?

```
ERROR: Execution of script 'test' failed! sessionStorage.getItem(...) is null userscript.html:4:370
```

Comment: Line 4 , col 370 ?

Answer (score 0):

That output means the error occurred on column 370 of line 4 in userscript.html. You can trace the error by clicking the userscript.html:4:370 on the right of the console and it should show you script and the line/command that caused the error.